# overload square bracket operator with private nested class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, nested-class, square-bracket

I want to overload the square bracket operator [] using a private nested class to differentiate between v[i] = val and val = v[i]

Comment: And which one should be called if you write `val2 = v[i] = val1`?

Comment: Good for you. What have you tried so far, and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: If it's a private nested class anyway, why not just provide methods whose names _clearly_ describe the (side-)effects, rather than some obscure what-this-does-depends-on-where-you-put-it behavior?

Comment: So do it.  It's a frequently used idiom.

Comment: If you're asking what the class needs to do, then you need an assignment operator for the first, and a conversion operator for the second. If you're asking something else, then please ask your question in the form of a question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a private nested class to distinguish these cases. Just make one const.

```
 public:
     T& operator[](size_t index);
     const T& operator[](size_t index) const;
```

If you do this, the const variant will be used in the const right-hand side case and the non-const one will be used when assigning to the element on the left-hand side.

Comment: No, that distinguishes between whether or not it's applied to a `const` object, not whether or not the return value is assigned to.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, right, that's why I said "const" right-hand side. (If the right-hand side is non-const, the non-const variant will be used). But I imagine that this is what the OP really needs.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work, because there could be a `const` or non-`const` instance on the RHS of the assignment.